# iPhone executable (MACH-O) decryption

Tags: iphone, encryption, executable, mach-o

I've been playing around with/debugging/disassembling binaries on the iPhone.

The first obstacle is that the binaries are encrypted and dissembler can not read them. This can be overcome by dumping the decrypted file content from gdb.

My question is about the decryption of binaries (which is done on the fly upon program start) for all MACH-O executable which have the encryption_id in LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO section, set to 1.

1. is there a tool that decrypts files for you? Any recommendations?
2. is there info available on how the process works? Apparently it's
   AES encryption? What key is used? Is it easy to replicate with your
   own program?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: So what you are asking about is how to crack other developers apps? I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to ask this question since it's main focus is about developing things - not reverse engineering apps developed by other. I think you might be better of at a hacker or piracy site.

Comment: Really? I thought stack overflow had a reverse engineering sound too it! (as in overflowing your stack with too much data...)

On a more serious note, I would think this is good general knowledge for all developers, and not some kind of tabu underground stuff.

Comment: user986919 is right, you cannot implement security into your app without knowing how a hacker would try to break it. If a typically compiled app can be reverse-engineered, obfuscate it some more on your own.

Comment: I can't really see anything in the question that indicates that the purpose of "disassembling binaries" is for the sake of improving the security of your own app. Knowing how to decrypt these doesn't help in improving the security of your app since the encryption/decryption is done transparently by iOS. If you want to see if there is anything in your own compiled app that is too easy to read by hackers, just disassemble the binary produced by Xcode before submitting it to Apple.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the security of a system being transparent. SSL is 100% transparent and yet it remains secure. On on iPhone, once it's jailbroken a lot of the security measures can be circumvented. Suppressing discussion about them on a public forum will not change that. It may make a few developers uneasy as they would prefer to think their apps are 100% impenetrable. Unless they are executed on the server - it's rarely the case.